# Hibernate (mapping) ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm just trying to get Hibernate to work for the first time...  I think I'm close, but I'm not sure why my mapping isn't working.

I have a class, User, and I have the following User.hbm.xml mapping for it.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="users">
        <composite-id name="id" class="User">
            <key-property name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="fname" type="string">
                <column name="fname" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="lname" type="string">
                <column name="lname" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try the following:

```
User user = null;
try {
    session.beginTransaction();         
    user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: User
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:148)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:131)
    org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:103)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:193)
    org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getComponentClass(Component.java:138)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:155)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:64)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:59)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:122)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:81)
    org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:180)
    org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:271)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    com.cloudfordev.controlpanel.HibernateUtil.configureSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    com.cloudfordev.controlpanel.GetController.greeting(GetController.java:19)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:947)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:878)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:946)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
```

Am I correct that this is a problem with my User.hbm.xml?

If so, what is the solution?

Thank you,

Comment: Try to add the qualified classname of user to your mapping.  Means with package names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the fully qualified class name for your class in

```
<class name="User" table="users">
```

So if your `User` class is in package `com.entities`, you would need to have

```
<class name="com.entities.User" table="users">
```

If your class is in the default package, put it in an actual package and save yourself the headaches further down the line.

Comment: That was it, so easy, thanks.  It's been a long road.

Comment: @LynnOwens You're welcome. Keep in mind that all libraries that use reflection require fully qualified class names.